# Ionic list + firebase binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I am building an app with Ionic and Firebase. I have a FirebaseArray that contains events with date on the server side.

I would like to be able to sort these events on the client side by date.

The goal is to populate a ion-list with these events and sort them by date (Today, this week, later).

The problem is that after retrieving all the events, I sort them in local $scope.arrays by date to populate the ion-list. Since it is not FirebaseArrays anymore, there is no binding between the data and the lists. (Work after retrieving the events but if I add another event to the FirebaseArray, it won't show up in the ion-list).

Does anybody can help me with how to deal with it? I don't need an actual code but more a way of thinking and maybe angularFire methods I am unaware.

Here is the service I am using:

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['firebase'])

.factory('Soirees', function($firebase, $firebaseArray) {
  var soireesRef = new Firebase('https://partey.firebaseio.com/soirees');
  var soirees = $firebaseArray(soireesRef);

  return {
    all: function() {
      return soirees;
    }, add: function(soiree) {
      soirees.$add(soiree);
    }, remove: function(soiree) {
      soiree.$remove(soiree);
    }, get: function(soiree) {
      return soirees.$getRecord(soiree);
    }
  };
});
```

And here is my controller:

```
.controller('EventsCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicLoading, Soirees) {

  $scope.soirees = Soirees.all();
  $scope.soireeDay = [];
  $scope.soireeWeek = [];
  $scope.soireeFurther = [];
  var currentDate = new Date();


  $scope.soirees.$loaded().then(function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.soirees, function(soiree){
      if (Math.abs(currentDate - soiree.date) <= 1000*60*60*24) {
        $scope.soireeDay.push(soiree);
      } else if (Math.abs(currentDate - soiree.date) > 1000*60*60*24 &&    Math.abs(soiree.date - currentDate) <= 7*1000*60*60*24) {
        $scope.soireeWeek.push(soiree);
      } else {
        $scope.soireeFurther.push(soiree);
      }
    })

    $scope.soireeDayNumber = $scope.soireeDay.length;
    $scope.soireeWeekNumber = $scope.soireeWeek.length;
    $scope.soireeFurtherNumber = $scope.soireeFurther.length;
  })

})
```

EDIT:
I am using the following filter:

```
.filter('soireeDay', function() {
  return function(item) {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    console.log(currentDate);
    if (Math.abs(currentDate - item.date) <= 1000*60*60*24) {
     return true
    } else {
     return false
    }}
})
```

in my html file: ng-repeat="soiree in soirees | filter:soireeDay"

But it looks liker filter is not called. Any hint ?

Thank you all,

Arnaud

Comment: Unless you show us the code of what you're currently doing, it will be hard to tell you how to improve it.

Comment: Rather than sorting them in your controller, use a filter.  Then you're just filtering the ng-repeat.

Comment: Can provide a Plunker or CodePen so it will be easier to provide a specific answer?   Here's the doc on [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do it by myself and if I can't succeed, I'll ping you. However, is it OK to filter 3 times the same firebaseArray (Today, this week, later)?

Comment: Have a look at this code, where I loop over the same `$firebaseArray` multiple times (it's in an inner `ng-repeat`/loop). Since it's just looping over the same collection, the data is retrieved only once: https://github.com/puf/trenches/blob/master/index.html#L53-L54 `ng-repeat='card in cards | filter:{state:state.$value}'`